# jQueryUI Tabs - New tabs using POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jQuery Tabs (from this example: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#manipulation) and want to add a new tab with contents from an external source. This external source requires POST parameters before data can be retrieved. The results back from the external source should create and populate a new tab showing those results on the new tab.

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    ajaxOptions: {
        error: function( xhr, status, index, anchor ) {
            $( anchor.hash ).html("Unable to load content for this form. Please contact your web administrator");}
    }
});

...

function addTab() {
  $.post(
    "/test.php", // External source URL
    { id: "11" }, // Sets POST data
    function (data) {
        $('#tabs').tabs("add", data, $tab_title); // should create a new tab with the results from the external source
    }
  );
}
```

What I have doesnt work. Anyone else have a working copy with this setup?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do an onLoad submit on the page which you're trying to source in the tab, then the result of that post, you can use `$(".ui-tabs-panel").html(postresponse);` and display it in the tab-wrapper, either that or change it to a GET (Querystrings) instead of POST, using GET would make something like this 10x easier.

Comment: if you use GET how would you prevent direct access to the page?